# Does discussions/gifts change anything?

Tags: danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc

In Dangaronpa, you can talk to people during your free time, and even give gifts.

Does that change anything in the game? The rest of the game seems pretty on rails. Like deciding to talk to Hina or Makoto doesn't seem to change much (like an extra clue in a trial).

So does discussing with somebody and gifting them gifts change anything to the story? And does the person you talk to may change something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the games in the Danganronpa series are linear visual novels with no branching paths, except for a BAD END here or there.  Making friends with your fellow victims and/or murderers, while getting you sweet sweet lore and a central part of the game, has no impact on the overarching story.

Getting to certain levels of friendship with characters will get you power-ups and options for the Class Trial segments which might make them easier to get through, but I don't think that's what you're really asking about.